# Intuitively explanation on spherical basis vectors?

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, curvilinear-coordinates

I have just started to (self) read [Tensors, Differential forms, and Variational Principles](https://doc.lagout.org/security/Crypto/Tensors%2C%20differential%20forms%2C%20and%20variational%20principles-Dover%20%281989%29.pdf) by Lovelock and Rund.

Section 2 of chapter 1 deals with vector components in curvilinear coordinates. For spherical coordinates, the gist is that:

- We have 3 surfaces: ρ = $c_1$ (or r), θ = $c_2$, and φ = $c_3$. [Sphere, cone,
  plane]
- Their intersections form curves. [Straight line, great circle,
  circle]

[image]

- We define the basis vectors as those tangents to those curves:

[image]

- We have a different basis for each point in space... (Always mutually orthonormal, yet different with respect to rectangular coordinates).

My questions started coming from the fact that we can describe a vector starting from a given point $P$ with respect to the basis at $P$, using spherical components $\bar{A_i}$ rather than rectangular components $A_i$.

$\mathbf{A}=\bar{A_1}\epsilon _1 + \rho \bar{A_2}\epsilon _2+\rho \;Sin(\theta )\bar{A_3}\epsilon _3$

I went and programmed a visualization [[Feel free to try it out!]](https://physics-unknowns.000webhostapp.com/) using visual python, in which I can move the point $P$ and give the spherical components for a vector:

[image]

What I do not get my head around is how a different radius or angle $\theta $ can change the 2nd and 3rd basis vector and thus the vector $\mathbf{A}$ as a whole, if I set $\theta =0$:

[image]

It vanishes! (Having $\bar{A_1}=\bar{A_2}=0$ for this example). The same happens with increasing radius for the 2nd and 3rd basis vectors.

**My take on this:** It obviously has to do with the fact that basis vectors are tangent to those curves, so the bigger the curve, the bigger the effects on the basis is. Or something related to them being tangent to those curves.

I'm looking for any other explanation, or a proper explanation regarding tangency in my idea in case it is not properly worded.

**Follow-up question:** Is a vector with the same spherical components seen differently by different points in space?

Thanks for any ideas you share!

Comment: >
>It vanishes! (Having A1¯=A2¯=0 for this example). The same happens with increasing radius for the 2nd and 3rd basis vectors.

I don't understand this

Comment: @Buraian It set those to zero to show how the 3rd component manifests alone without the other 2 interfering with the visualization. 

Try out my program, set A1¯=A2¯=0 and A3¯ any nonzero value, then play with the theta parameter (2nd on  the top side)

[The 3 parameters on the bottom define A1¯, A2¯, and A3¯ respectively.]

Comment: Are you saying that $e_{\phi}$ and $e_{\theta}$ get larger as you go further from the origin? @Fernado Garcia Cortez

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble understanding, could you rephrase the mentioned part? / add pictures to show what you mean more explicitly?

Comment: @Buraian For sure! Not a problem. Check this gif I recorded: https://tenor.com/bCJEl.gif   || The point is, there are vectors which, in some places, will vanish (all components go to zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I do not get my head around is how a different radius or angle θ can change the 2nd and 3rd basis vector and thus the vector A as a whole, if I set θ=0:

Good. You self discovered [the hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem). (*)

"If f is a continuous function that assigns a vector in R3 to every point p on a sphere such that f(p) is always tangent to the sphere at p, then there is at least one pole, a point where the field vanishes (a p such that f(p) = 0)."

> Follow-up question: Is a vector with the same spherical components seen differently by different points in space?

In the way we view intrinsic geometry, given a point on the surface, we draw a tangent plane on this surface and use the tangent vectors at that point to span this basis. We can't really add or subtract vectors between two points on the surface unless we define a notion of connection (maybe I am wrong here, please comment if so)

---

*: 59:57 of [this lecture](https://youtu.be/UbQS40KHkH0?t=3600) by prof. schuller has a nice discussion

Comment: Thanks for your input, much appreciated! I will take a look at the hairy ball theorem. I have added the option to show the tangent plane (in the visualization) in case you want to check it out. And yeah, this last question does involve thinking about intrinsic geometry. Though we have a vector outside the tangent plane (the epsilon1 basis vector), it is the only one not affected by position.